# Seccond nginx site dosen't work

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

i have weird problem where first reverse-proxy site works fine but if im trying to add seccond `site-enabled` with almost identical settings just few major changes  like `server_name` nginx simply won't start or reload. If i remove new `site-enabled` it works fine.

Here is working site code:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/shop_header;

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.classybrothers.com classybrothers.com;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/shop_etc;

}
```

shop_header:

```
server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

upstream shop {
  server 127.0.0.1:2500;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  return 404;
}
```

shop_etc:

```
access_log /home/web/shop/logs/access.log;
error_log /home/web/shop/logs/error.log;

location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

  proxy_pass http://shop/;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

It works fine. But if i want to add my seccond site with subdomains and different port nginx wont start. Here is code of seccond site:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/ttt_header;

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.ttt.classybrothers.com ttt.classybrothers.com;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/ttt_etc;

}
```

header:

```
server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

upstream ttt {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  return 404;
}
```

etc:

```
access_log /home/web/ttt/logs/access.log;
error_log /home/web/ttt/logs/error.log;

location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

  proxy_pass http://ttt/;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

I can't figure out this problem for a while now. Would be great if anyone who ever had this problem to suggest me what could I do to solve it.

EDIT: problem solved, it was `server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;` removing it fixed the problem. My guess that if one site already runs it other dosen't need to repeat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your configuration is not valid, a reload generates an error message, usually being helpful by explaining what was wrong and where.

Both `shop_header` and `ttt_header` define a `server` listening on port 80 with no `server_name`, thus being the 'default' server for this port.

You cannot have several `server` blocks with the same `listen` and `server_name` values.

Comment: my nginx dosen't generate any message but simply dosent respond to reaload command. thanks for answer by the way.

Comment: The 'reload' command from the kindly give nservice file, simply issue a SIGHUP signal to the master process. Check that the service uses the right pid file or manually issue the signal and chek the logs.